# Keep state while navigating between component in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Let's say I want to have a reusable react component in my project. I also want that component to have its state under different locations without losing it during component unmount. What is the correct way to deal with this kind of architecture in React? In other words, when the user navigates between these two routes react unmounts the previous component, therefore it loads remote data on every navigation between /user and /groups routes.
I also know that there is something called Redux. I don't see a clear way how to do it using reduct. Do I need two reducers? one for Users and the other for Groups? If so it's quite inconvenient creating a new reducer and write new logic each time when I need to use ReusableComponent.
Here is a similar skeleton to describe what I am trying to do. Any hint would be helpful.

```
//Router example
<Router>
   <Switch>
       <Route exact path=”/users” >
           <UserComponent>
               <ReusableComponent url=”http://apidomain.com/users” />
           </UserComponent>
       </Route>
     <Route exact path=”/groups” >
           <GroupComponent>
               <ReusableComponent url=”http://apidomain.com/groups” />
           </GroupComponent>
       </Route>
   </Switch>
</Router>

//ReusableComponent Example
<ReusableComponent>
    --->use url, that passed from parent component tree(users or groups) to load data and keep in state
    <ReusableComponentContext> 
        <Head />
        <Body />
        <Footer />
   </ReusableComponentContext>
</ReusableComponent>
```

**EDIT**
So to describe my problem better is I need to have the same component with two or more parallel state on the different locations without overriding each other. If it's possible

Comment: You can use redux, localStorage, sessionStorage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "React Context" api. The context wrappes your app so if one component updates/ rerenderes the state which is stored inside of the context stayes untouched. To use Context you need three files:

*"UserContext" = Example => rename!*

### Context Component (UserContext)

```js
import { createContext } from "react"

export const UserContext = createContext(initValue)
```

### Parent Component (Provider)

//filename: UserContext.js

```js
//* import React, { useState } from "react"
//* import UserContext from "./UserContext"


  const [state, setState] = useState("initState")
  
//* return(
  <UserContext.Provider value={{state, setState}}> //value="props"
      <ChildComponent/> 
  </UserContext.Provider>
```

### Child Component (Consumer)

```js
//*import React, { use Context } from "react";
//*import {UserContext} from "./UserContext"

  const data = useContext(UserContext) //here "UserContext"
```

src: [short explenation of usage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhMKvyLRWo0)

### Edit: consuming with a custom hook

To avoid one import-statement you can create a custom Hook like this

```js
import React, { use Context } from "react";
import {UserContext} from "./UserContext";

const useUserContext = (()=>{
    const {state, setState} = useContext(UserContext)
//use effect if you want to set the context? with the hook...
    return[state, setState]
})
```

in your remounting component

```js
import useUserContext from "./useUserContext"

//rfce{
const {state, setState} = useUserContext()
//}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how context works. In context world I need to put them on the top level of routing, otherwise react unmounts them when I navigate on a different route

Comment: The problem is that if I have ten places where I need to use ReusableComponent I need to create ten context provider for each and nest all the routes ten times in the route components tree. I am not sure that's a correct way

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. In my case, I had some misunderstanding on what level put context provider tag in the router component tree.  So in React, it's very important to put the context provider wrapper in the right location. It holds a dedicated state only for those child components that are wrapped by that context provider.

In my case, I had **ReusableComponentContext** inside **ReusableComponent** and that was the wrong approach Because everywhere I used **ReusableComponent** it had individual context(Therefore individual state). I moved **ReusableComponentContext** on the top of a couple of components to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can connect `ReusableComponent` to a piece of your redux store (see [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) for more details).

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const ReusableComponent = (props) => {
    // some logic before return
    return <div>{props.magicProperty}</div>
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ magicProperty: state.magicProperty });
return connect(mapStateToProps)(ReusableComponent);
```

So every time you use `ReusableComponent` in you app, the `magicProperty` is shared, You can also connect some actions to the component in order to manage that part of state in the classical redux flow.

Comment: Nowadays there are easier ways to use redux, using useDispatch and useSelector hooks, but the structure looks too complicated.  As I understand react doesn't allow the creation of a singleton reusable component that can keep the state automatically.

Comment: Once the parent component is unmounted its state is lost as well